# Get lat/lng of points along the route after every 100m in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Map Api V2 I have drawn a route on the map. Now i wish to save this route in my database.

So I need to get the lat/lng of points on the route say after each 100 meters which i will save as a polygon. How can i do it in Google Map V2 in android.

i am stuck on it from last 10 days but not getting a solution.
any help will be appriciable :)

```
public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
    public static final String TAG_SLAT = "sourcelat";
    public static final String TAG_SLONG = "sourcelong";
    public static final String TAG_DLAT = "destinationlat";
    public static final String TAG_DLONG = "destinationg";

    private static LatLng Source = null;
    private static LatLng Destination = null;

    private GoogleMap map;
    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private LatLngBounds latlngBounds;
    private Button bNavigation;
    private Polyline newPolyline;
    private Marker smarker;
    private  Marker dmarker;
    Geocoder geocoder;

    private boolean isTraveling = false;
    private int width, height;
    private String sourcelat;
    private String sourcelong;
    private String destinationg;
    private String destinationlat;
    double slat;
    double slong;
    double dlat;
    double dlong;
    double d;
    double tempDistance;
    String distance;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isConnectingToInternet = false;
    String ts;
    LatLng latLng;
    GPSTracker gps;

    List<Address> addresses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        isConnectingToInternet = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isConnectingToInternet) {
            Intent in = getIntent();
            sourcelat = in.getStringExtra(TAG_SLAT);
            destinationlat = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DLAT);
            destinationg = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DLONG);
            sourcelong = in.getStringExtra(TAG_SLONG);


            slat = Double.parseDouble(sourcelat);
            slong = Double.parseDouble(sourcelong);
            dlat = Double.parseDouble(destinationlat);
            dlong = Double.parseDouble(destinationg);
            Source = new LatLng(slat, slong);
            Destination = new LatLng(dlat, dlong);

            getSreenDimanstions();

            fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            map = fragment.getMap();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            ImageButton cureent_location = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clocation);
            cureent_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onLocationChanged();
                }
            });

            if (!isTraveling) {
                isTraveling = true;


                findDirections(Source.latitude, Source.longitude, Destination.latitude, Destination.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);


            } else {
                isTraveling = false;

            }
        }else {
            AlertUtils.showAlertDialog(NavigationActivity.this, "No Internet Detected", "Please check your internet connection.", false);
        }
    }
    public  double calculateDistance(double fromLatitude,double fromLongitude,double toLatitude,double toLongitude)
    {

        float results[] = new float[1];

        try {
            Location.distanceBetween(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, toLongitude, results);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Source.equals(Destination)){
            distance="0";
        }
        else {
            int dist = (int) results[0];
            if (dist <= 0)
                return 0D;

            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            results[0] /= 1000D;
            distance = decimalFormat.format(results[0]);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(distance);
            double speed = 40;
            double time = d / speed;
             ts = manual(time);
            Log.v("fdf", String.valueOf(ts));


        }
        return d;
    }
    private static String manual(double eta) {
        int hour = (int) eta;
        eta =  (eta - hour) * 60;
        int minutes = (int) eta;
        eta =  (eta - minutes) * 60;
        int seconds = (int) eta;
        eta =  (eta - seconds) * 1000;
        int ms = (int) eta;
        //Log.d("ffgfh", String.valueOf(eta));
        return String.format("%dHr %dMin ", hour, minutes);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(Source, Destination);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 100));



    }

    public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);
        //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(Source).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions().position(Destination).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));


        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++)
        {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));


        }
        if (newPolyline != null)
        {

            newPolyline.remove();
        }
        newPolyline = map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        //smarker = map.addMarker(marker);
        dmarker = map.addMarker(marker1);
        if (isTraveling) {

            latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(Source, Destination);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 100));
            Dialog dialog_help = new Dialog(this);
            dialog_help .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog_help.setContentView(R.layout.title_multi_selectitems_dialog);

            calculateDistance(slat, slong, dlat, dlong);
            TextView dis = (TextView) dialog_help.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            dis.setText("Distance   " + distance + "Km   ");
            TextView tim = (TextView) dialog_help.findViewById(R.id.time);
            tim.setText("Time          " + ts);
            dialog_help.setCancelable(true);
            dialog_help.setTitle("Distance & Time" );

            dialog_help.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog_help.show();

            dialog_help.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            dialog_help.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY));
            dialog_help.getWindow().setLayout(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        else {

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 100));
        }

    }

    private void getSreenDimanstions()
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth(); 
        height = display.getHeight(); 
    }

    private LatLngBounds createLatLngBoundsObject(LatLng firstLocation, LatLng secondLocation)
    {
        if (firstLocation != null && secondLocation != null)
        {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(firstLocation).include(secondLocation);

            return builder.build();
        }
        return null;
    }



    public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

            GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);


            try {
                asyncTask.execute(map);

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


    }


    public void onLocationChanged( ){
        TextView cl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        isConnectingToInternet = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isConnectingToInternet) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(NavigationActivity.this);
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
             latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String prmises = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3);
            cl.setText(address + " " + prmises + " " + city + " " + country);
        }else {
            AlertUtils.showAlertDialog(NavigationActivity.this, "No Internet Detected", "Please check your internet connection.", false);
        }
    }





    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with this map application: http://maps.cloudmade.com/.

At first you create your route with waypoints. Click on the button "Get directions" (upper left corner) and create your route (clicking on the map). After that you can export (there is a button on the upper right corner) your route (include waypoints) to a gpx-or a json-file. You can load both files to a GIS.

Comment: thanx this is exactll i  need.